# Interrupt calls/SMSs on iPhone IOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

Can we interrupt calls/SMSs on iPhone IOS 5? any code samples?
I am looking for some code samples for an application that gets notified when a call is incoming/outgoing to/from the phone, and gets the caller number.
Same thing for SMSs.

I know this seems like spying, but the purpose of this at the end is way far of that.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take this from a non-jailbroken position (because you do not specify it in your question).

> Can we interrupt calls/SMSs on iPhone IOS 5?

No.  Absolutely not.  In doing so, you'd need 3 things:

1. A Listener For Incoming Calls/SMS's
2. An Event Called When A Call Or SMS is Incoming.
3. A Responder Able To Cut Off Said Call

The first is impossible without breaking out of the app sandbox, a clear no-no in iOS development.  It also presents a major security risk for the operating system as a whole.  If applications could listen to each other and react any way they wanted, it would create chaos!  Users wouldn't have any privacy whatsoever.  The second would require some kind of listener that was always present and capable of waking/starting your app to interrupt the call, which again, is a clear case of stepping out of the sandbox.  In fact, the only way to launch your application to interrupt the call would be to send a URL, which in itself requires an application... Yikes!  The third is just plain impractical.  If you made even a tiny mistake in the way you determined whether or not to cut off the call or SMS, you could prevent potentially important messages from getting to innocent bystanders.

> I know this seems like spying

Because it is!  You need a listener in order to evoke some action from your application.

Of course, this isn't to say it's impossible, but it would require a jailbroken device.